# onActivityResult not getting called after calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity who's functionality is to take screenshot of the current screen. This is how the onCreate method looks like for that activity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(null)

    mProjectionManager = getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
    startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Then right below it, I have the onActivityResult method that looks like this:

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data)

        val externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null)
        if (externalFilesDir != null) {
            STORE_DIRECTORY = externalFilesDir.absolutePath + "/screenshots/"
            val storeDirectory = File(STORE_DIRECTORY)
            if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
                val success = storeDirectory.mkdirs()
                if (!success) {
                    Log.e("TAGE", "failed to create file storage directory.")
                    return
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "failed to create file storage directory, getExternalFilesDir is null.")
            return
        }

        // display metrics
        val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
        mDensity = metrics.densityDpi
        mDisplay = windowManager.defaultDisplay

        // create virtual display depending on device width / height
        createVirtualDisplay()

        // register orientation change callback
        mOrientationChangeCallback = OrientationChangeCallback(this)
        if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
            mOrientationChangeCallback.enable()
        }

        // register media projection stop callback
        sMediaProjection.registerCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler)
    }
}
```

This is how the activity looks like in the Manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".ScreenshotActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

My problem is that the onActivityResult function is never called, I have tried to add breakpoints in that function but they are never hit.

Comment: What is the value of `REQUEST_CODE`? Also, I think you need to remove the `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` part.

Comment: As above - check the request code.

Comment: The value of the request code is 100

Comment: @CommonsWare it doesnt work even after I have removed android:excludeFromRecents="true" . The request code is 100 as mentioned above

Comment: @NoelOmondi, there is suspicious code `super.onCreate(null)` - you need to pass `savedInstanceState` here. Also, do you have any errors or warnings printed in console?

Comment: [Here are two media projection projects that work](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection). Compare what you have to what I have and see what differs (beyond programming language, as those samples are in Java).